# QListView how to add column?

Tags: qt, qlistview

How can I add columns to QListView control. Found a method addColumn while seardhing, but in my **Qt Creator 1.2.1 based on Qt 4.5.2(32 bit)** QListView doesn't have such method at all !!!

So how would I add columns ?

Say I have 3 columns then what is the code to add a row ?

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`QTableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) for this purpose. But if you need `QListView` look & feel, you can use `QTableView` borderless using Qt Stylesheet. Also you may want to add an icon. You can add icons to your `QTableView` by setting icon data to `Qt::DecorationRole`.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot add a column, cause list views are designed to view simple lists. You need QTable[View/Widget].

Answer (score 6):

`QListWidget` is a single column only. Use `QTreeWidget/View` for multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

As the start point you could watch how works `QTableView` class here: http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.2/sql-tablemodel.html and do the similar things with `QListView`. So, you can't just emit `addColumn()` for `QListView` class, first you need to create model and then do `listView->setModel(model)`.

Comment: It will not work due to QListView realization. It accept multicolumn models, but show only one of these. When you connect such model, you should set setModelColumn(index) to specify one the list will show.